# Differential Calculus : word problem

Tags: calculus

I have this question in my maths book.

> A spherical balloon has radius $10$ units. Show that the percentage increases in its volume is approximately $0.3$ units, if its radius increases $0.1$ percent.

I have solved it as

$$v = \frac43\pi r^3 \\
dv= \frac43\pi 3r^2 dr \\
dv = 4\pi r^2 dr \\
dv = 4\pi (10)^2 (0.1/100) \\
dv = 0.4\pi .$$

But now how do I prove that the increase in its volume is approximately $0.3$ units?

Comment: The balloon volume increases as the cube of the radius. Which means if you increase the radius by a factor of $1.001$, you increase the volume by a factor of $$1.001^3 = 1.003003001$$

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a mistake in the question. If we take things numerically:

$V(r)=4/3*\pi r^3 \approx 1333\pi $

$V(r+r*0.1/100) = 4/3 *  \pi*(10+10*0.1/100)^3 \approx 1337\pi $

So the increase in volume is $\Delta V = (1337-1333)\pi = 4\pi $ which is not 0.3 units.

However, $4/1333 \approx 0.3\%$, so the volume has been increased by $0.3\%$.